# Email Etiquette: Continuing on Email Chain to Reschedule Missed Meeting

Tags: email

I made a mistake with scheduling for a big meeting. The meeting was scheduled over email as a sort of 2-on-1 where my direct supervisor and I would present an idea to someone much higher up than us.

After going back and forth on the chain for a bit we set a time, but I misread the last email in the chain and entered the wrong time in my calendar. Because of distance, I missed the meeting and it went on without me.

I've already apologized to and worked with my direct supervisor to get caught up on what happened, but she wants me to schedule another meeting with the higher up so I can go over technical details with him in more detail (this was supposed to be my role in the meeting).

My question is how I should send this email (not necessarily it's content, which I believe I've already worked out). Should it be sent in the same email chain as before? Should I change the subject? Send a new email with the same subject as the previous chain? Or a new email with a new subject entirely?

(First question here, let me know if there's anything I should do to improve.)

Comment: You're probably overthinking it. As a side note: can't you just create a meeting in your calendar and invite them to it?

Comment: There isn't a right answer here. Sometimes it's easier to start a new email chain, because the new email is at the top of the inbox, but you lose all of the context of the chain. I would just reiterate that you were unable to make the previous meeting and am scheduling another one.

Comment: @Dukeling Since my schedule is more open compared to his, I'm planning on asking what time works for him rather than stating one time as an invite.

Comment: @jcmack That makes sense, it would probably be easier to start a new chain so it isn't cluttered with messages from setting up the previous meeting.

Comment: @KevinG. You can also send out an invite after agreeing on a time. I can't remember the last time I had a meeting at work that wasn't either impromptu or in my calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a new email.

Apologize for the confusion relating to the previous meeting and propose a new time after ensuring that your supervisor is ok with the new time-slot.

Be clear and unambiguous about your wording and you should be fine.

It's understandable that details get lost and confused in a long email trail, so don't worry about it so much.